# Simpson’s rule for monomial degree > 4

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, numerical-calculus, simpsons-rule

Does there exist a monic $x^n$, n > 4, for which Simpson’s rule is exact? If not, why?

$$ S(f) = \frac{b-a}{6}f(a) + \frac{2(b-a)}{3}f(\frac{a+b}{2})+ \frac{b-a}{6}f(b)$$

Comment: Hint: set $a=0,b=1$ and try.

Answer (score 1):

If you take, for sake of simplicity, $a=0, b=1$ (and $f(x)=x^n$) you would require that
$$
\frac 16 f(0) + \frac 23 f(1/2) + \frac 16 f(1) = \frac{1}{n+1}
$$

i.e.

$$
\frac 23 (1/2)^n+\frac 16 = \frac{1}{n+1}\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2^{n-2}}=\dfrac{5-n}{n+1}
$$

However, if $n>4$ this last equality is impossible.

Comment: Why is it impossible?

Comment: @Picard: try to find solutions.

Comment: I already tried. I am having trouble proving that it is impossible..

Comment: What are the signs on either side of the equation?

Comment: if $n\ge 5$ the rhs is $\leq 0$, but the lhs is $>0$. They cannot be equal.

Answer (score -2):

Simpson's rule approximates a function, f(x), when integrating $\int_a^b f(x)dx$,  by dividing the interval from a to b an odd number of subintervals, then taking the quadratic that passes through each set of three points. If f is quadratic function the Simpson's rule would approximate it by itself so give an exact answer.

If f(x) is a function of "quadratic type", say $ax^4+ bx^2+ c$, where we can write $y= x^2$ to become $ay^2+ by+ C$, that will Simpson's rule would give an exact value for that.

As for monic polynomials, $x^8$ or $x^{12}$ will work.

Comment: This does not seem to address the question. Note that $n>4$.

Comment: This is wrong, you forgot the rule of change of variables.